How do vaishnavas interpret the Tryambaka hymn, accounting for all the internal vedic explanations of it provided in the Brāhmaṇa-s?
I know that they think the hymn is for Nṛsiṃha/Saṃkarṣaṇa etc. My question is specifically how.

Śatapatha Brāhmaṇa and Gopatha Brāhmaṇa as well as other texts such as Sarvānukramaṇī of Kātyāyana, Bṛhaddevatā of Śaunaka etc. are unanimous that Tryambaka is indeed Rudra; the father of the Maruts, the physician among the physicians.



@Sipivista According to Shri Madhvacharya, Parabrahman Shriman Narayana is "sarva shabdha vaacha." All names are His names and describe His karya, kirti, and supremacy.
